# Getting ImportError: cannot import name 'total_budget_left' from 'walletapp.views' in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am working on one Django web application. And getting the `ImportError: cannot import name 'total_budget_left' from 'walletapp.views'`.
I want to import `total_budget_left` this variable from one function of `walletapp`'s `views.py` to another app's `views.py` 's function.

My `walletapp.views.py`

```
def budgetView(request):
    preference = UserPreferences.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if preference:
        prefered_currency = UserPreferences.objects.get(user=request.user)

    budgets = Budget.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    total_budget = sum(budgets.values_list('amount', flat=True))
    if budgets:
        for bud in budgets:
            cdate = bud.created_date
            edate = bud.end_date
        
        expenses = Expense.objects.filter(owner=request.user, date__gte=cdate, date__lte=edate)
        total_expense = sum(expenses.values_list('amount', flat=True))
        total_budget_left = total_budget - total_expense
```

I want to import the variable `total_budget_left` into another app function `myapp.views.py`

My `myapp.views.py`

```
from walletapp.views import total_budget_left  
 
def index(request):
        print(total_budget_left)
```

Even after trying multiple ways, I am not able to proceed, please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in the directory?

Comment: `total_budget_left` is a local variable inside of a function.  It can't be imported.  Instead, save it to the session, and then other views can fetch it from the session.

Comment: @SorinBurghiu Yes I am having `__init__.py` file in that directory

Comment: @JohnGordon Basically I am going to use that variable in cronjobs so I think the session key will require `request` as a parameter, and in the cronjob function, we can't pass any parameter to `settings.py` while using that function.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `budgetView`, save the value in the session:

```
def budgetView(request):
    ...
    request.session['some_key'] = some_value
```

Then another view can fetch the value from the session (assuming `budgetView` was called first):

```
def someOtherView(request):
    some_value = request.session['some_key']
```

Comment: I want to use the variable in `cronjobs`, so in `settings.py`, I am using `CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'mainapp.cron.budgetDelete', '>> /cron/django_cron.log 2>&1')
]` this logic so I cant pass the `request` parameter here. `budgetDelete` is the function without parameters. Any way to solve this?